# How can I include and use a command line tool in my my java lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to do some data transformation using a command-line tool (Tarql). I am unsure on how to include the command line tool in my deployment package. I was thinking of saving it in a tmp folder so that I could work with it through ProcessBuilder but I don't know how to include it in my deployment package in the first place.

Another issue that I am facing is I don't know how to save files from an s3 bucket to the tmp folder.

My Code so far:

```
public class LambdaTarqlExecution implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LambdaTarqlExecution.class);
    private AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
    public LambdaTarqlExecution() {
    }
    // Test purpose only.
    LambdaTarqlExecution(AmazonS3 s3) {
        this.s3 = s3;
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Received event: " + event);
        // Get the object from the event and show its content type
        S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord record=event.getRecords().get(0);
        String bucket = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();

        try {

            ObjectMetadata object1 =  s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, "GeoMappings.sparql"),new File("/tmp/"));
            ObjectMetadata object2 =  s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, "Countries.csv"),new File("/tmp/"));
            String[] command;
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/tmp/tarql.bat", "--write-base", "--base","ontologies.se.com/Procurment", "/tmp/GeoMappings.sparql", "/tmp/Countries.csv", ">", "/tmp/geo.ttl");
            PutObjectResult result = s3.putObject("turtleFiles", "geo.ttl", "/tmp/geo.ttl");

        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        return "sucess";
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your description isn't too clear ("how to save get and same multiple files"). Could you possibly edit your question to describe what you are trying to do and what problem you are currently facing? FYI, I notice that your code is not calling the `downloadFile()` function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited my post, does it make more sense now?